# Howto Disable links inside table while chk is checked using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this code

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
         <th>Person</th>
        <th>Doc</th>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="lnk">
                <td><%# Eval("person") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("doc") %></td>
                    <td> <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Checked=' <%# Eval("active") %>' Enabled="false" runat="server" /></td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="show.aspx?id=<%# Eval("document") %>">Details</a> |
                    <a class="lnk-h" href="edit.aspx?id=<%# Eval("document") %>">Edit</a> |
                    <a class="lnk-h" href="destroy.aspx?id=<%# Eval("document") %>">Delete</a>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

I need chek if person it is active or not,
if it is inactive, i want hide links delete and edit

can any helpme please

i started with this code but isent work

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
          $(".lnk").each(function () {
           if( $(this).children("input:checkbox").is(":checked"))
           {
               $(this).children(".lnk-h").css("display","none");
           }
       });
   })
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot see any DOMs with class "lnk" that it would loop?

Comment: oh sorry, i added it

Comment: i was making tests, sorry again, but it is only an idea and not work, im learning jquery but i cant solve this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot use children() as it is only checking children just under given DOM element.

DOM elements under lnk are all `<td>` which is why it will not find selectors "input:checkbox" and ".lnk-h".

You should use "find" that goes through all children:

```
if( $(this).find("input:checkbox").is(":checked"))
    {
        $(this).find(".lnk-h").css("display","none");
    }
```